# Python - Convert string-numeric to float

Tags: python, regex, typeconverter

I have the following string numeric values, and need to keep only the digit and decimals. I just can't find a right regular expression for this.

```
s = [
      "12.45-280", # need to convert to 12.45280
      "A10.4B2", # need to convert to 10.42
]
```

Comment: So would your first expected output value be the float -267.55 or the string "12.45-280"?

Comment: What regex's have you tried, and what results did they give?

Comment: Tried `[0-9\.].?` ?

Comment: That will match `one digit or period` followed by `zero or one (any) character`.  I think that will match two character at the start of s[0] and none of s[1], correct?  Edit your question and show what you wanted it to do - exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove all non-digits and non-dot characters, then convert the result to float:

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: s = [
   ...:       "12.45-280", # need to convert to 12.45280
   ...:       "A10.4B2", # need to convert to 10.42
   ...: ]

In [3]: for item in s:
   ...:     print(float(re.sub(r"[^0-9.]", "", item)))
   ...:     
12.4528
10.42
```

Here `[^0-9.]` would match any character except a digit or a literal dot.

Comment: Only one dot should be allowed in a number. Also a leading minus sign for negative numbers shoudl be accepted.

Comment: @VPfB good points that might be needed to be taken into account, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Convert each alphabetical character in the string to empty char ""

```
import re
num_string = []* len(s)
for i, string in enumerate(s):
    num_string[i] = re.sub('[a-zA-Z]+', '', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a combination of `locale` and regular expressions:

```
import re, locale
from locale import atof

# or whatever else
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_GB.UTF-8')

s = [
      "12.45-280", # need to convert to 12.45280
      "A10.4B2", # need to convert to 10.42
]

rx = re.compile(r'[A-Z-]+')

def convert(item):
    """
    Try to convert the item to a float
    """
    try:
        return atof(rx.sub('', item))
    except:
        return None

converted = [match
            for item in s
            for match in [convert(item)]
            if match]

print(converted)
# [12.4528, 10.42]
```